# How many $n-sequences$ consisting of $0s$ and $1s$ are such that a $1$ follows a $0$ for the first time on the $(n-1)^{st}$ and $n^{th}$ transmission?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

How many $n-sequences$ consisting of $0s$ and $1s$ are such that a $1$ follows a $0$ for the first time on the $(n-1)^{st}$ and $n^{th}$ transmission?

I found this question in my university textbook, and I simply don't understand what the question means/wants. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, there aren't very many.  If $n=4$, say, then the good sequences are $0001, 1001, 1101$.    I suggest:  work it out for other small $n$ until you see how to do it in general.

Comment: Okay, but I want to understand how you came up with the sequences: $0001,1001,1101$
That's what I actually do not understand; the terms under which the sequences are valid.

Comment: Well, we know the third entry is 0 and the fourth is 1 and that this combination didn't appear prior to the end.  So we know the word is $XY01$ and thus there are only 4 words to consider.  $0101$ fails since $01$ appears prior to the end,  the other three work.

Comment: For $n=3$ you have words of the form $X01$ and here $X$ can be either $0$ or $1$, both of which work.  For $n=5$ you get $00001, 10001,11001,11101$.  That ought to make the pattern clear.

Comment: Okay, so what I've come up with so far:
The sequence must end with a $01$, thus leaving us with $n-2$ places to work with, each place can have a value of a $1$ or $0$ provided that all the ones that are chosen must precede all the zeros. In other words we have $(n-2)$ ones and $(n-2)$ zeros with respect to order, and now we want to choose $(n-2)$ adjacent elements of the $2(n-2)$ elements we have, which is calculated like this: $2(n-2)-(n-2)+1=(n-1)$.
So the number of possible $n-sequences$ is $(n-1)$

Is that it? any notes?

Comment: The answer is right, but I am not sure I follow your reasoning. Might just be a matter of phrasing. The good words of length $n$ all have the form $1^a0^b01$ where $a+b=n-2$ and $a,b≥0$.  such words are determined by $a\in \{0, \cdots, n-2\}$ so there are $n-1$ of them.